# Why in (stochastic) gradient descent the gradient vector (including length) is considered instead of just its direction?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

When implementing gradient descent (or stochastic gradient descent) I don't understand why instead of just the DIRECTION of the gradient the actual gradient vector is used.

I'm actually using the normalized direction (using $L^\infty$ norm) multiplied by learning rate (also dynamically updated during search) and it seems to work better.

What confuses me about the use of gradient vector instead of gradient direction is that for example minimizing $F(x)$ or minimizing $\alpha + \beta F(x)$ will impact exploration of parameter space when instead it's just a scaling+shifting of the loss function and, in my opinion, it shouldn't change the way we look for the optimum location in parameter space (ideally optimizing $F(x)$ or $g(F(x))$ when $g$ is any smooth monotonic increasing function $ℝ → ℝ$ should in my opinion lead to an equivalent exploration).

Clearly when $g:ℝ→ℝ$ is a smooth increasing function the direction of  $\nabla g(f(x))$ is the same as the one of $\nabla f(x)$ but the length is not:
$$
\nabla g(f(x)) = g'(f(x)) \nabla f(x)
$$

What is the logical explanation for using the gradient vector instead of just the direction of the gradient vector?

Comment: I don't know so I won't answer the question, but I thought the idea was that the amount you needed to alter the values was proportional to the size of the gradient?

Comment: One reason: when you are close to the minimizer, the gradient gets smaller in magnitude so that the updates automatically get smaller. If you use the normalized gradient you will then "overshoot". It might therefore make sense to multiply the gradient with the step size times the minimum of 1 and then magnitude of the gradient.

Comment: @PhoemueX: of course there is a risk of overshooting (another thing I don't understand is why in what is normally described as the gradient descent you don't just "back-up" undoing the last step if loss is worse and decrease the learning rate; it's another thing I do and that works better). Also note that the implication is in the other way around... if you are in the minimum then the gradient is zero, if the gradient is zero it doesn't mean you're in the minimum (you could be in a plateau) and if the gradient is small it doesn't mean you're close to the minimum (you could be in a valley).

Comment: Actually the learning rate is here to adjust the length

Comment: @Lelouch: ok... but this sounds to me like "the length is irrelevant, but we can compensate for it". The gradient length however changes over weights space and the learning rate is normally fixed or changing with a scheduling that just depends on the iteration count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the assumptions you want to place on the function you are optimizing and on the step size schedule. For example, if the function is convex and $L$-Lipschitz, as is often assumed, then we know that:

$$f(x^+) \leq f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T\left(-t\frac{\nabla f(x)}{\|\nabla f(x)\|} \right ) + \frac{L}{2} \left\| t \frac{\nabla f(x)}{\|\nabla f(x)\|}\right\|^2$$

when we write $x^+ = x - t\nabla f(x)/\|\nabla f(x)\|$ as you've defined the iteration. Can you see what is the optimal choice of $t$ in this case (just set the derivative equal to $0$)?

Another way to think about it is that using the gradient direction and norm provides you with more information about the function you are optimizing than just using the direction. The norm of the gradient tells you how fast the function is changing at that point, so it makes sense that you would want to incorporate that information into your choice of step. This is similar to why using second order information also helps with convergence (for example in newtons method).

As for your idea about using a smaller step size when the next value is too large, I am not aware of any proof showing that that technique converges faster than regular gradient descent, but it seems like a reasonable approach to me.

Comment: I'm still very confused and making practical experiments. Solving the equation I got $x^+ = x - {\nabla f(x) \over L}$ but I'm not really sure of what that means in practical terms. Awarding the bounty because you at least took the time to look at the question.

Comment: Exactly, the optimal choice depends not only on the direction of the gradient, but also the magnitude. So for the case of Lipschitz smooth functions that should give you an idea of why we use the gradient rather than the unit vector in the direction of the gradient.

Comment: I don't think I can agree on the conclusion... $t$ computed this way is IMO not "optimal" under any meaningful practical sense. After all what you get is only about the minimal value of a $\le$ relation (i.e. a worst case result) under a global assumption ($L$). I hope you agree that the "best" step when minimizing $f(x)$ should be the same as the "best" step to minimize $g(f(x))$ where $g$ is any smooth monotonic increasing ℝ→ℝ function. Clearly the gradient direction is the same in this case but gradient length is not ($\nabla g(f(x)) = g'(f(x)) \nabla f(x)$).